# Apache2 reverse proxy and refused HTTPS connection

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy, ssl

I'm running Docker on my server and have started an Apache2 container, which acts as a reverse proxy for all incoming requests.

I have started an OnlyOffice docker container on my Docker, and I have configured the OnlyOffice instance to use HTTPS, adding some self-signed certs. If I access the server with `https://serverip:onlyofficeport`, everything works as expected, but I would like to proxy the requests from the outside through my reverse proxy to the OnlyOffice container.

Config:

```xml
<VirtualHost *:443>

  SSLEngine on
  SSLProxyEngine on

  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

  SSLCertificateFile      /etc/letsencrypt/live/defg.com/fullcha$
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/defg.com/fullcha$
  SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/letsencrypt/live/defg.com/privkey$

  ServerAdmin webmaster@defg.com

  SSLProxyVerify none
  SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
  SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
  SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

  ProxyPreserveHost on
  ProxyPass "/" "https://172.17.0.12:444/" retry=0
  ProxyPassReverse "/" "https://172.17.0.12:444/"

  ServerName abcd.defg.com

</VirtualHost>
```

Unfortunately, this does not work and I get the following errors:

```
[proxy:error]      [pid 60]  (111) Connection refused: AH00957: HTTPS: attempt to connect to 172.17.0.12:444 (172.17.0.12) failed
[proxy:error]      [pid 60]  AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (172.17.0.12) for 0s
[proxy_http:error] [pid 60]  [client 192.168.30.24:64712] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 172.17.0.12
```

It seems Apache cannot connect to the OnlyOffice instance, and on the webpage it shows me `503, Service unavailable`.  How do I proxy the requests from the outside through my reverse proxy to the OnlyOffice container?

Comment: You might want to look into linked containers. This is ultimately what you need to do this without exposing other containers’ ports. It will also give you named access, so changes in the containers’ IP addresses won’t matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved.

I had to use the IP Address of the Server itself instead of the docker container IP-Address.

This is strange, since I usually use the IP Address of the Docker Container.

Comment: im experimenting same issue, by chance can this be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63262632/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host-neterr-http2-pr